# How can I get latest ssh daemon to work on my server for remote connection?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, server, openssh, pci-compliance

I'm trying to get PCI compliant, and I'm required to have a version above 6.6. I compiled the latest version of OpenSSH, and on the server it shows the correct version when I do ssh -V or sshd -V. (OpenSSH_7.2p1, OpenSSL)

However, a telnet to the port (and thus the PCI compliance scan) still gets a reference to the old version of the server.

When I do a "which sshd" I get */usr/local/sbin/sshd*, however, sshd also exists in */usr/sbin/sshd*.

I thought changing the reference in run levels would work, but it doesn't have any effect.

Any ideas why the new version isn't being referenced, and thus used for remote SSH?

Comment: `/usr/sbin/sshd` is started with full path. You need to modify the systemd service file or whatever is starting your service.

Comment: I had also modified the ssh service file located in /etc/init.d to point to /usr/local/sbin/sshd, along with the run levels (to be more specific). Am I still missing a separate file? I feel like I am.